# SMOTE for multi-instance learning i.e num_rows(x_train) > num_rows(y_train)

Tags: dataset, data-science-model, class-imbalance, smote, multi-instance-learning

I have an imbalanced dataset and I wish to predict classes(0 or 1).

Sample `x_train`:

```
id      date    c1   c2 . . . . . .  c20
101  13-02-2015  2    7 . . . . . .   14
101  14-02-2015 24    7 . . . . . .    8
  .
  .
  .
105  13-02-2015 12    5 . . . . . . .  4
  . 
  .
```

Sample `y_train`

```
id   class
101    1
105    1
107    0
 .
 .
 .
```

Now I wish to over sample class 0 in the dataset but the problem is for each `id` I have just one row in `y_train` whereas I have 50 rows for the same `id` in `x_train`.

Answer (score 1):

What you have here is called Multi-Instance Learning. From Wikipedia

> In machine learning, multiple-instance learning (MIL) is a type of supervised learning. Instead of receiving a set of instances which are individually labeled, the learner receives a set of labeled bags, each containing many instances.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_instance_learning

The approach you take in this case is different. You need to bring the Multi-Instance Learning problem into a Single-Instance Learning one. One way you can do this is:

1. Perform for each bag of instances a K-Means clustering
2. Calculate the Hausdorff distance of each instance from each of the cluster
3. Use those distances as features and keep the label from the y_train set

Then apply SMOTE on the new dataset (where you have one row for features and label) and any kind of model of Single-Instance Learning.

You can find details in this [Review of Multi-Instance Learning and Its applications](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~juny/MILL/review.htm)